# What is the meaning of 'have' in this sentence?

Tags: word-meaning, gerunds

I read the sentence like 'On the grounds behind the castle they have hunting.'
What is the meaning of 'have' in this sentence?
Maybe, it means 'On the grounds behind the castle they have been hunting.'or
'On the grounds behind the castle they are hunting.'?

Answer (score 1):

*Have* can be used to say you host an event or facility for an activity.  An "-ing" word can be used to describe the activity hosted or facilitated.

Examples include an event ...

> I am having a party at 3:00.

or something that people can come on to a property and enjoy.

> They have kayaking at the water park today.
>
> At the carnival they have darts, face painting, and folk singing.

In your example, it sounds like the castle is open to the public and people can participate in hunting activities on its grounds.